# Bijection between $\mathrm{hom}(A, B)$ and $\mathrm{hom}(1, B^A)$

Tags: category-theory

$
\newcommand{\hom}{\mathrm{hom}}
$Suppose that $A, B$ are objects of a category with all finite products and exponentials, $\mathbb{C}$. Show that there is a bijection between $\hom(A, B)$ and $\hom(1, B^A)$ where $1$ is a terminal in $\mathbb{C}$.

My attempt:
Consider the isomorphism given by transposition, $\hom(1 \times A, B) \cong \hom(1, B^A)$. It suffices to show that $\hom(A, B) \cong\hom(1 \times A, B)$. Since $1$ is terminal, there is unique morphism from any object $Z$ to $1$, $k_Z$. Consider $g \in \hom(A, B)$. We can define an isomorphism by $g \mapsto k_A \times g$. This must be an isomorphism since $k_A$ is unique.

This seems correct to me but I'm a little doubtful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is right, but I don't think your proposed isomorphism $\newcommand\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(A,B)\simeq \Hom(1\times A,B)$ makes any sense at all.

I.e., you propose sending $g : A\to B$ to $k_A\times g : 1\times A \to A\times B$, which is not an element of $\Hom(1\times A,B)$.

Instead, it suffices to show that $A\simeq 1\times A$, since then $\Hom(A,B)\simeq \Hom(1\times A,B)$.

For this, we use the Yoneda lemma. Since we have
$$\Hom(Z,1\times A)\simeq \Hom(Z,1)\times \Hom(Z,A) \simeq \{*\}\times \Hom(Z,A)\simeq \Hom(Z,A),$$
the Yoneda lemma tells us that $1\times A\simeq A$.

**Edit**

If you're not familiar with the Yoneda lemma, Matematleta points out that you can also see $A\simeq 1\times A$ by noticing that $(A,(k_A,\textrm{id}_A))$ is also a product for $1$ and $A$. (If $f:Z\to 1$ and $g:Z\to A$, then $g$ is the unique map from $Z$ to $A$ such that $k_A\circ g = f = k_Z$, and $\textrm{id}_A\circ g = g$).

Comment: Isn't this overkill? $A\simeq 1\times A$ simply because $(A,\langle id_A,!\rangle)$ is also a product.

Comment: @Matematleta Sure, that also works, I just personally find this more immediately clear. But that's also quite clear and nice. I think I just generally like to think of products as representing functors in the first place.

Comment: I only pointed this out because from the OP's attempt, it seemed to me that he/she hasn't seen Yoneda yet. No problem with your answer (which I was happy to upvote!), I think of products that way too, ---

Comment: @Matematleta Hm, good point, I'll edit that in as a second viewpoint.

Comment: @Matematleta Thanks! I was trying to read up on Yoneda lemma, but the isomorphism you provided is cleaner.

Comment: Why is it that the existence of such a product implies there is an isomorphism?

Comment: @real_father Products are unique up to unique isomorphism. So if $A$ is the product of $1$ and $A$, then there is a unique isomorphism between $A$ and $1\times A$. (In fact, $1\times A$ is only defined up to unique isomorphism, so we can say $A$ *is* the product of $1$ and $A$.)